# How to uninstall odbc for Ejabberd?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have installed Ejabberd with odbc_mysql before, but I want to use mnesia now, so I removed odbc by:

```
{auth_method, internal}.
%% {auth_method, odbc}.
```

But when I close mysql service, and restart ejabberd , I found that there are connection error:

```
E(<0.333.0>:ejabberd_odbc:542) : mysql_conn: post_start error connect_failed
```

So how to removed odbc ?

Comment: I suspect the problem might be due to the fact ejabberd's configuration file is used to bootstrap the "real" configuration storage which uses internal Mnesia tables (no matter whether you're using ODBC or not), and you might need to *override* them using special configuration file directive like `override_global.`, and/or `override_local.` -- refer to the section "3.1  Basic Configuration" of the manual.

Comment: OK, I posted my comment as an answer. Please consider commenting which of these two configuration file statements helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem might be due to the fact ejabberd's configuration file is used to bootstrap the "real" configuration storage which uses internal Mnesia tables (no matter whether you're using ODBC or not), and you might need to override them using special configuration file directive like `override_global.`, and/or `override_local.` -- refer to the section "3.1 Basic Configuration" of the manual.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure about this but I think you will need to comment out the odbc_server config too i.e. the line where you have provided the server credentials,

```
{odbc_server, {mysql, "server", "database", "username", "password"}}.
```

Also make sure that there are no other modules using odbc eg. `mod_roster_odbc` or `mod_archive_odbc` in case you were using them initially.